# PowerPivot database not deleted from tabular database

Tags: sql-server, powerpivot, ssas

I am testing SharePoint 2013 / SQL Server 2014 combination.
I upload a PowerPivot Excel to PowerPivot gallery and do some testing.

I notice that when I delete the PowerPivot from the PowerPivot gallery, the database in PowerPivot SQL server is not deleted.

I uploaded the same PowerPivot several 4 times during testing, and now there is 4 databases in SQL server even tho I have deleted all PowerPivots from the gallery.

How are the databases deleted?

Comment: Are you talking about the PowerPivot Service application DBs or are you talking about the Content DB? u saying when u add a new item in powerpivot gallery its create a new database?

Comment: Content DB of powerpivot instance. But this morning the databases was deleted. So I guess the power pivot that users open are in memory for configured time, and during that time a corresponding db is visible in powerpivot ssas tabular instance.

Answer (score 0):

By this morning the databases had been deleted by SharePoint. I suppose the databases are in the PowerPivot SSAS tabular instance for the duration that it is configured to be in memory in the PowerPivot settings.

Also the DB for a powerpivot that I had not deleted was deleted from the PowerPivot instance, but re-created when I open the PowerPivot from SharePoint.